# Is it possible to have a CollapsingToolbarLayout with multiple layouts?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I want to have the following UI:

```
Title -  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
Subtitle app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
List of items
```

I want to display only the subtitle when user is at the bottom and scrolls a little. I want to display the title when user scrolls from the bottom till it reaches the top.

The problem is that I cannot set the app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" and app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll| exitUntilCollapsed" to the items in the LinearLayout (title_layout and subtitle_Layout). How can I fix this?

Here is my current layout UI:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coord_toolbar_layout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"       
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                  
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/item_layout"
                        layout="@layout/title_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        />

                    <ViewStub
                        android:id="@+id/subtitle_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                        app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/stub"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"         
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `collapsemode` instead of scrollFlags for the childs of `collapsing toolbar`. And use `pin` or `parallax` etc etc depending upon your needs.. `if(userReachedBottom){ appBar.setExpanded(true);}`and on `scrollStateChanged` of nestedscroll or your scrolling view `title.setVisibility(Vsisible);` and `subtitle.setVisibility(Gone);` and at the bottom `title.setVisibility(Gone);` and `subtitle.setVisibility(Visible);`